# 802.11n PCI/(USB okay, not preferred) card that can do AP/master mode

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I am looking for a 802.11n wireless card that Linux supports that can be dropped into AP/master mode.

I would prefer PCI, but USB would be tolerable, just not preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most wifi station cards do not work in AP/master mode.

However Atheros cards do..

USB cards

http://www.atheros.com/technology/technology.php?nav1=47&product=78

http://www.atheros.com/technology/technology.php?nav1=47&product=81

PCI Express Cards

All Atheros PCIe cards should be operable in AP/master mode. ath9k supports master mode, so all cards that are supported by ath9k should work in the AP/master mode

Comment: I will look into the USB cards, but I am really looking for PCI { not PCIe ( a PCI card might not exist, though. ) }

Comment: PCI cards are hard to come by these days. Laptops have PCIe slots nowadays so the ODMS have stopped produce the PCI form factor. You could use a PCIe to PCI converter

Comment: And actually, that Atheros pointer helped, I managed to find a wireless N *PCI* adapter with an Atheros chipset, and someone claiming that that model handled master mode with a tutorial. Win.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumbles on this -- Using the Atheros pointer that freethinker gave me, I managed to find the TP-Link TL-WN951N

Which has an atheros chipset and someone wrote a tutorial about the very card and master mode.